# Using FacePlusPlus API with python

Tags: python, image-processing, face

Im getting the following error.

```
'error_message': 'BAD_ARGUMENTS
```

when I execute this python code.

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.post(
    'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect',
    {
        'api_key': "******",
        'api_secret': "********",
        # 'image_url': img_url,
        'image_base64': 'iop.jpg',
        'return_landmark': 1,
        'return_attributes': 
'headpose,eyestatus,facequality,mouthstatus,eyegaze'
    }
)

print(response.json())
```

I have been stuck on this for quite a long time and have no clue of whats the error. I checked the website and it says 'Error while parsing some arguments. This error may be cause by illegal type or length of argument.'
But have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `image_base64` parameter should be the contents of the image file, base64 encoded (eg, a really long string).